# Understanding of vectorization with SSE instructions

Tags: c, assembly, x86, vectorization, auto-vectorization

I try to understand how vectorization with SSE instructions works.

Here a code snippet where vectorization is achieved :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 10000

void test1(double * restrict a, double * restrict b)
{
  int i;

  double *x = __builtin_assume_aligned(a, 16);
  double *y = __builtin_assume_aligned(b, 16);

  for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
  {
    x[i] += y[i];
  }
}
```

and my compilation command :

```
gcc -std=c99 -c example1.c -O3 -S -o example1.s
```

Here the output for assembler code :

```
 .file "example1.c"
  .text
  .p2align 4,,15
  .globl  test1
  .type test1, @function
test1:
.LFB7:
  .cfi_startproc
  xorl  %eax, %eax
  .p2align 4,,10
  .p2align 3
.L3:
  movapd  (%rdi,%rax), %xmm0
  addpd (%rsi,%rax), %xmm0
  movapd  %xmm0, (%rdi,%rax)
  addq  $16, %rax
  cmpq  $80000, %rax
  jne .L3
  rep ret
  .cfi_endproc
.LFE7:
  .size test1, .-test1
  .ident  "GCC: (Debian 4.8.2-16) 4.8.2"
  .section  .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

I have practiced Assembler many years ago and I would like to know what represents above
the registers %rdi, %rax and %rsi.

I know %xmm0 is the SIMD register where we can store 2 doubles (on 16 bytes).

But I don't understand how the simultaneous addition is performed :

I think all happens here :

```
      movapd  (%rdi,%rax), %xmm0
      addpd (%rsi,%rax), %xmm0
      movapd  %xmm0, (%rdi,%rax)
      addq  $16, %rax
      cmpq  $80000, %rax
      jne .L3
      rep ret
```

Does %rax represents "x" array ?

What does %rsi represent in C code snippet ?

Does the final result (for example a[0]=a[0]+b[0] is stored into %rdi ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: You're generating 64 bit code and the rXX registers are just the 64 bit versions of the usual x86 registers (e.g. eax = 32 bit, rax = 64 bit).

Comment: Use `-fverbose-asm` to have gcc put comments on each instruction, giving a name for each operand.  (Often they're just numbered tmp names, but sometimes you get a meaningful C variable name.  Especially for array indexing.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first thing you need to know is the calling conventions for 64-bit code on Unix systems. See [Wikipedia's x86-64_calling_conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#x86-64_calling_conventions) and for much more detail read Agner Fog's [calling conventions manual](http://agner.org/optimize/calling_conventions.pdf).

Integer parameters are passed in the following order: rdi, rsi, rdx, rcx, r8, r9. So you can pass up six integer values by register (but only four on Windows). This means in your case that:

```
rdi = &x[0],
rsi = &y[0].
```

The register `rax` starts at zero and increments `2*sizeof(double)=16` bytes each iteration. It is then compared with `sizeof(double)*10000=80000` each iteration to test if the loop is finished.

The use of `cmp` here is actually an inefficiency in the GCC compiler. Modern Intel processors can fuse the `cmp` and `jne` instruction into one instruction and they can also fuse `add` and `jne` into one instruction but they *cannot* fuse `add`, `cmp`, and `jne` into one instruction. But it's possible to [remove the `cmp` instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25921612/produce-loops-without-cmp-instruction-in-gcc).

What GCC should have done is set

```
rdi = &x[0] + 80000;
rsi = &y[0] + 80000;
rax = -80000
```

and then the loop could be done like this

```
movapd  (%rdi,%rax), %xmm0       ; temp = x[i]
addpd (%rsi,%rax), %xmm0         ; temp += y[i]
movapd  %xmm0, (%rdi,%rax)       ; x[i] = temp
addq  $16, %rax                  ; i += 2
jnz .L3                          ; then loop
```

Now the loop counts from `-80000` up to `0` and does not need the `cmp` instruction and the `add` and `jnz` will be fused into one micro-operation.

Answer (score 3):

```
  movapd  (%rdi,%rax), %xmm0       ; temp = x[i]
  addpd (%rsi,%rax), %xmm0         ; temp += y[i]
  movapd  %xmm0, (%rdi,%rax)       ; x[i] = temp
  addq  $16, %rax                  ; i += 2
  cmpq  $80000, %rax               ; if (i < SIZE)
  jne .L3                          ; then loop
```

The rax register represents the `i` variable, but stored as a byte index, rdi is &x, rsi is &y.  Each pass through the loop adds *two* doubles, thus the increment of rax by 2 * sizeof(double) or 16 bytes.