# Is cv::Mat::clone() more efficient than assigning a matrix created by cv::Mat::zeros()?

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a function that is executed many times in the application lifespan. In order to optimize the code, which solution is better?

Is this:

```cpp
void foo() {
    static const cv::Mat zeroMat16 = cv::Mat::zeros(rows, cols, CV_16UC1);
    cv::Mat newMat = zeroMat16.clone();
    ...
}
```

faster than this:

```cpp
void foo() {
    cv::Mat newMat = cv::Mat::zeros(rows, cols, CV_16UC1);
    ...
}
```

Or the efficiency is pretty much the same?

Comment: why don't you profile it?

Comment: @Miki Because it's less error-prone if someone with more experience than me could give a general and motived answer, instead of using a profiler whose results depend on many factors and it gives you no explanation.

Comment: I do not recommend using the first method. Not only the program uses unnecessary memory but also it does not improve the performance.

Comment: @Burak so clone() and zeros() have the same computational cost?

Comment: Most probably. See [the implementation of `zeros`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/5ac0712cf1f25af2224afd1776ca9476e39f85d8/modules/core/src/matrix_expressions.cpp#L1751).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**`clone`**](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/b87f7a625eb0cd5239a27f1d15c4ce791d0951f4/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp#L820) uses `copyTo` without mask in its implementation.

```cpp
inline Mat Mat::clone() const
{
  Mat m;
  copyTo(m);
  return m;
}
```

[**`copyTo`** implementation](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/5ac0712cf1f25af2224afd1776ca9476e39f85d8/modules/core/src/copy.cpp#L239) <kbd>-></kbd> [***`memcpy`***](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/5ac0712cf1f25af2224afd1776ca9476e39f85d8/modules/core/src/copy.cpp#L320)

---

[**`zeros`** implementation](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/5ac0712cf1f25af2224afd1776ca9476e39f85d8/modules/core/src/matrix_expressions.cpp#L1746)
<kbd>-></kbd>
[`makeExpr`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/5ac0712cf1f25af2224afd1776ca9476e39f85d8/modules/core/src/matrix_expressions.cpp#L1705)
<kbd>-></kbd>
[`MatExpr`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/b87f7a625eb0cd5239a27f1d15c4ce791d0951f4/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp#L3440)

which is then converted from `MatExpr` to `Mat`

[`MatExpr::operator Mat()`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/b87f7a625eb0cd5239a27f1d15c4ce791d0951f4/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp#L3446)
<kbd>-></kbd>
[`assign`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/b87f7a625eb0cd5239a27f1d15c4ce791d0951f4/modules/core/src/matrix_expressions.cpp#L1677)

which calls `m = Scalar();`

[`Mat::operator=`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/b87f7a625eb0cd5239a27f1d15c4ce791d0951f4/modules/core/src/copy.cpp#L440)
<kbd>-></kbd>
[***`memset`***](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/b87f7a625eb0cd5239a27f1d15c4ce791d0951f4/modules/core/src/copy.cpp#L456)

---

### [`memcpy` is only slighly slower than `memset`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43168595/memcpy-takes-the-same-time-as-memset#question:%7E:text=memcpy%20is%20only%20slighly%20slower%20than%20memset)

(~0.2 sec over 1 GB data),

which results **`zeros`** is slightly faster than **`copyTo`**.

---

### **Conclusion:**

By using `zeros` instead of `clone`,

- Unnecessary memory allocation is prevented.
- The performance is increased very slightly.

Comment: can this depend on the device/platform/OS?

Comment: @Micka Given the source code and steps up to memcpy/memset functions, the implementation is platform independent. `copyTo` function has different `memcpy` implementations [for CUDA](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/5ac0712cf1f25af2224afd1776ca9476e39f85d8/modules/core/src/cuda/gpu_mat.cu#L224), or [takes advantage of IPP](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/5ac0712cf1f25af2224afd1776ca9476e39f85d8/modules/core/src/copy.cpp#L298) if possible. I didn't see such thing for `zeros`.

Comment: are memcpy and memset independent from the hardware, operating system and compiler it is used on?

Comment: @Micka That is beyond my knowledge. I can only say that these are the fastest functions for dynamically created memory.